# How can I change the width of angular material button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

How can I change the width of angular material button? I am using angular 6.

Comment: show us what you already tried?

Comment: There is a simple button <button mat-raised-button>Show</button>.I want to reduce its width

Comment: Got the answer.Must use min-width
Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148095/is-it-possible-to-make-an-md-button-smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148095/is-it-possible-to-make-an-md-button-smaller)

Comment: min-width is not working with version 8.1.1

Answer (score 36):

You could attach a class and manipulate that.

```
<button mat-raised-button class="my-class">Show</button>
```

then in the CSS / SASS file

```
.my-class{
      width: 100px!important;
      min-width: unset!important;
}
```

This should ensure the attribute is overwritten.
BR

Comment: But the width is not decreasing beyond a certain limit .It is only increasing but the issue is with decreasing.

Comment: Regarding [this suggested edit of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21430659): please do not try to edit posts which are clearly off-topic. All you added was more reason to close it as being a tool-recommendation, or even Primarily Opinion Based. Another problem is that the first edit on a question after it has been put on hold puts a question into the reopen queue, whereas subsequent edits won't. You therefor take the OP's chance for improving the question. Do keep editing, just make sure they're worth it!

Comment: `min-width` was my problem. Thanks

Comment: Most welcome :')

Comment: min-width: unset!important; that was the key ;)

Answer (score 1):

Merely add a style attribute (a way of diverses to do it) :

```
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" style="width : 10em;">Primary</button>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdnftl?file=app/button-types-example.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```
<button mat-raised-button>BUTTON</button>
```

Or in CSS, without `!important` property:

```
mat-raised-button {
 width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Supposing this is your button:

```
<button id="myButton" mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```

You can go ahead an add id to button:

```
#myButton {
width: 150px;
}
```